# GridView.setOnItemClickListener is not triggering

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-studio-2.3

I am trying to add a feature where, whenever the user clicks on an editText to start typing in the last empty gridview item, a new empty gridview item will be added. The problem is that the listener doesn't get called when the user starts typing. I know there are some questions here about similar issues, but my gridView has an editText in it which is what I think the problem is.

Here is the listener I have:

```
roleLayout.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            System.out.println(roleArrayList.get(position).getRole() + "******");
            if(roleArrayList.get(position).getRole().equals("")) {
                if (roleArrayList.size() == 1 ) {
                    roleArrayList.add(new NewRoleElement());
                } else {
                    if (!roleArrayList.get(roleArrayList.size() - 1).getRole().equals("")) {
                        roleArrayList.add(new NewRoleElement());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

And here is the xml code for my `GridView`:

```
<GridView
      android:id="@+id/roleList"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:numColumns="1"
      android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
```

Here is my xml code for the actual item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/my_layout_bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/roleText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter a new role"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:text="Repeat?" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My adapter code is here:

```
public class RoleAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    Context c;

    public RoleAdapter(Context context) {
        this.c = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return roleArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return roleArrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return roleArrayList.indexOf(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.role_template, null);

        }
        roleArrayList.get(position).setRoleInput((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.roleText));
        roleArrayList.get(position).setRepeatCheckBox((CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox));
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your adapter code

Comment: I think the problem is with your EditText inside the GridView. Try setting the onClickListener  or addTextChangedListener for your EditText inside the ArrayAdapter

Comment: I can try this @karthikvishnukumar , but how would I be able to add a new item to the GridView from inside the editText class?

Comment: @Dotnetpickles It is now included

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that `EditText` and `CheckBox` capture the focus

Try this in your code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="48dp"
   android:layout_rowWeight="1"
   android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
   android:background="@drawable/my_layout_bg"
   android:orientation="horizontal">
   ......
</LinearLayout>
```

Add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in the root xml code .

**Another way**

Also you can set `android:focusable="false"` in the `EditText` and set `android:clickable="false"` in the `CheckBox`.

Comment: I tried both methods, but the listener still doesn't get called.